# Changing one argument of a multivariable function at each step of Fold

Tags: functions, functional-style

I have a function, call it `F[a_List,b_,c_,d_]` which takes in 4 arguments. Now I want to compose this function with itself, where the number of compositions I want to perform is given by the length of `a`. For that I thought I could use `Fold`, but I am not sure how to set it up. There is something else. At each step of `Fold`, one of my arguments changes, namely `a`changes and also at each step the output of applying `F` replaces `b`. For instance, say `a` is a list of length 4. I would like to get the final output of:

`F[a[[4]],F[a[[3]],F[a[[2]],F[a[[1]],b,c,d],c,d],c,d],c,d]`

Can I do that using `Fold`? Or is there some other, hopefully more efficient way?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I believe I do not, b is being successively replaced by the output of applying F as we go through the composition. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, my bad.  I was on a phone and had trouble matching all the brackets by eye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Fold` as follows:

```
Fold[F[#2, #, c, d] &, b, Array[a, 4]]
```

> F[a[4], F[a[3], F[a[2], F[a[1], b, c, d], c, d], c, d], c, d]

Comment: that's nice! Thank you.